# How do I reroute to a domain name from an elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an Elastic IP in AWS. When I navigate to my elastic IP, I want it to redirect me to a domain name. For example in cmd, I type `ping google.com` it returns `Reply from 172.217.13.238`, when i navigate to `172.217.13.238`, it takes me to `google.com`. I want to do this same thing but with an elastic IP and a route 53 domain name.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no magic here. Visiting the IP address normally will go to the default host of the webserver. You can make it redirect to redirect whatever domain you want, just return a 3XX status code with a location.

Comment: purchase a domain either from aws or 3rd party ( incase of 3rd party) just add namservers of aws to this third party name servers after creating public hosted zone.
create a A record which maps hostname to IP addresses which in your case will be an elastic IP. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a domain in Route 53 and point it at your elastic IP address.